# Magento generate coupon codes programmatically

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, module, coupon

I would like to create unique coupon codes automatically.

I have tried the following - when using setCouponCode() to generate coupon code, i must set static code. Example:

```
$code = "abc"; 
setCouponCode($code);
```

I would like this to be a unique random string instead.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You want to generate a bunch of random codes programmatically? or you want to know how to make a random string?

Comment: i want generate a bunch of random codes programmatically

Comment: From where would you like to do this, is this an external script? And what code do you have so far except the 2 lines above?

Comment: Give this a try: http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.com/2010/04/create-bulk-discount-rules.html

Comment: @SanderMangel: i have a page, when customer access to it, they enter their email and system will generate a coupon code for them.

Comment: well if you're looking for a way to generate random strings you can use this:
`$rstr = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 10);` If you want more info on how to create the coupons itself I suggest posting a bit more info on what you already have and what kind of coupons you want etc. I'ts a bit vague for me

Comment: @rocky if that's the answer you were looking for this question is a bit off topic since it isn't related to Magento but PHP

Comment: I understand the question and an answer is forthcoming.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about PHP, not Magento specifically

Comment: No - it is not off topic. This is doable in plain Magento.

Comment: After my edit is this now clearer? I understand the goal and have provided an extremely workable solution. The feedback from Rocky is clear that this is not a question about how to generate random strings.

Comment: @SanderMangel your 'random' generator will never have repeat digits, is sufficiently less random than the in-built Magento generator.

Comment: @philwinkle I stand corrected, you're right. Using Magento's default method is better.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Magento has this facility in-built since 1.7CE.**

The class `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Coupon_Massgenerator`. To make use of it on your own you can instantiate the class:

```
$generator = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon_massgenerator');
```

You need to set some options:

```
$data = array(
    'max_probability'   => .25,
    'max_attempts'      => 10,
    'uses_per_customer' => 1,
    'uses_per_coupon'   => 1,
    'qty'               => 5, //number of coupons to generate
    'length'            => 14, //length of coupon string
    'to_date'           => '2013-12-31', //ending date of generated promo
    /**
     * Possible values include:
     * Mage_SalesRule_Helper_Coupon::COUPON_FORMAT_ALPHANUMERIC
     * Mage_SalesRule_Helper_Coupon::COUPON_FORMAT_ALPHABETICAL
     * Mage_SalesRule_Helper_Coupon::COUPON_FORMAT_NUMERIC
     */
    'format'          => Mage_SalesRule_Helper_Coupon::COUPON_FORMAT_ALPHANUMERIC,
    'rule_id'         => 1234 //the id of the rule you will use as a template
);
```

Validate that the $data is correct:

```
$generator->validateData($data);
```

And then save those options to the generator:

```
$generator->setData($data);
```

And now, GENERATE!

```
$generator->generatePool();
```

They're populated into `salesrule_coupon`:

[image]

It works reasonably well - you'll have to fetch back out *which* coupons were generated though. To do that, you may look under "Manage Coupon Codes" tab of the shopping cart rules:

[image]

If you need to get them programmatically:

```
$salesRule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($data['rule_id']);
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('salesrule/coupon_collection')
            ->addRuleToFilter($salesRule)
            ->addGeneratedCouponsFilter();
```

You can get a count of how many were generated successfully if you need:

```
$generator->getGeneratedCount();
```

Comment: thanks, very detail although it seem not correct with my question, but it's a way

Comment: To just generate (one) coupon make the "qty" field 1. Use the collection as prescribed and issue "getLastItem"

Comment: And to get the last coupon code you can call `getLastItem()->getData('code')`

Answer (score 2):

the options for data array can be,

```
$generator = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon_massgenerator');
$data = array(
    'uses_per_customer' => 1,
    'uses_per_coupon'   => 1,
    'qty'               => 1,  //number of coupons to generate
    'length'            => 16, //length of coupon string
    'to_date'           => date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 month",  time())), //ending date of generated promo
    'prefix'            => 'rev',
    'suffix'            => 'tf',
    'dash'              => 5,
    /**
     * Possible values include:
     * Mage_SalesRule_Helper_Coupon::COUPON_FORMAT_ALPHANUMERIC
     * Mage_SalesRule_Helper_Coupon::COUPON_FORMAT_ALPHABETICAL
     * Mage_SalesRule_Helper_Coupon::COUPON_FORMAT_NUMERIC
     */
    'format'          => Mage_SalesRule_Helper_Coupon::COUPON_FORMAT_ALPHANUMERIC,
    'rule_id'         => 1 //the id of the rule you will use as a template
);
$generator->validateData($data);
$generator->setData($data);
$generator->generatePool();

$salesRule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($data['rule_id']);
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('salesrule/coupon_collection')
            ->addRuleToFilter($salesRule)
            ->addGeneratedCouponsFilter();
```