# Registration and sent coupon code

Tags: coupon, code

If user register with website and send to the coupon code  for that customer.
How to get the coupon code and sent to the customer?
Is it possible to generate coupon code automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this post and create your own codes:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/7917

For send email with generated coupon you can create a module, with event observer *customer_register_success* that generate the coupon and send email