# Coupons are invalid, but succesfully generated programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9

I use this method to generate coupons with a specific SalesRule template that is existing.

```
/**
     * @param null|Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule $rule
     * @param int $amount
     * @throws Mage_Core_Model_Store_Exception
     */
    public function createCoupons($rule = null, $amount = 5)
    {
        if ($rule == null && !is_null($this->salesRuleObject)) {
            $rule = $this->getRule();
        }

        /** @var Mage_SalesRule_Model_Coupon_Massgenerator $generator */
        $generator = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon_massgenerator');
        $data = [
            'max_probability' => .25,
            'max_attempts' => 5,
            'uses_per_customer' => 1,
            'uses_per_coupon' => 1,
            'qty' => $amount,
            'length' => 8,
            'format' => Mage_SalesRule_Helper_Coupon::COUPON_FORMAT_ALPHANUMERIC,
            'dash_every_x_characters' => 4,
            'prefix' => "PH-",
            'rule_id' => $rule->getId()
        ];

        if ($generator->validateData($data)) {
            $generator->setDash($data['dash_every_x_characters'])
                ->setPrefix($data['prefix'])
                ->setData($data)
                ->generatePool();
            $rule->setCouponCodeGenerator($generator);
        };
    }
```

They are generated properly and inserted into my Database, which I can verify with `SELECT * FROM salesrule_coupon` -> it has 5 coupons after I run this method.

However, if I try to use one of the coupon in the cart it keeps show me message coupon code is invalid.

Whats wrong with the generation of the codes? Am I missing something? Does the rule needs to be worked on after generate the code?

Further information on this topic: [Magento generate coupon codes programmatically](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7916/magento-generate-coupon-codes-programmatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I forgot to properly set up the customer_group_id attribute in the rule properly.

`$salesrule->setCustomerGroupId([0,1,2])->save()`

This made usage for all groups possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to create coupon programatically. I had used this code before, it is a tested code. It will surely work

Set parameters accordingly

```
$generator = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule');
$coupon_code = 'abc-xyz';
$data = array(
    'product_ids' => null,
    'name' => $value,
    'description' => null,
    'is_active' => 1,
    'website_ids' => array(1),
    'customer_group_ids' => array(0,1,2,4), //Available customer groups
    'coupon_type' => 2,
    'coupon_code' => $value,
    'uses_per_coupon' => 1,
    'uses_per_customer' => 1,
    'from_date' => null,
    'to_date' => null,
    'sort_order' => null,
    'is_rss' => 0,
    'rule' => array(
        'conditions' => array(
            array(
                'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_combine',
                'aggregator' => 'all',
                'value' => 1,
                'new_child' => null
            )
        ),
        'actions' => array(
            array(
                'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_product_combine',
                'aggregator' => 'all',
                'value' => 1,
                'new_child' => null
            )
        )
    ),
    'simple_action' => cart_fixed, //Fixed amount discount for whole cart
    'discount_amount' => 100,
    'discount_qty' => null,
    'discount_step' => 0,
    'apply_to_shipping' => 0,
    'simple_free_shipping' => 0,
    'stop_rules_processing' => 0,
    'store_labels' => $coupon_code
);
$validateResult = $generator->validateData(new Varien_Object($data));
if ($validateResult == true) {
    $generator->loadPost($data);
    if($generator->save()){
        return $generator;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will create a new Rule entity each time I want to generate a Rule which fills the Database in the long run. My approach is to keep loading on DB as low as possible. I fixed my issue by adding customer_group_ids.